# How do you write an INNER JOIN with an "OR" in Linq

Tags: linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I am trying to write a Linq query to generate the following SQL

```
SELECT 
    [t1].[Id], [t2].[value3]
FROM 
    [Table1] AS [t1]
INNER JOIN 
    [Table2] AS [t2] ON [t1].[Id] = [t2].[value1]
                     OR [t1].[Id] = [t2].[value2]
```

I have seen lots of examples for how to do *multiple* joins, but none for how to do this type of "one or the other" join.

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = from t1 in context.Table1
             from t2 in context.Table2
             where (t1.Id == t2.value1 || t1.Id == t2.value2)
             select new 
                    { 
                        t1.Id,
                        t2.value3
                    };
```

Answer (score 0):

**INNER JOIN**

```cs
var query = 
    from t1 in context.Table1
    from t2 in context.Table2.Where(t2 => t1.Id == t2.value1 || t1.Id == t2.value2)
    select new 
    { 
        t1.Id,
        t2.value3
    };
```

**LEFT JOIN**

```cs
var query = 
    from t1 in context.Table1
    from t2 in context.Table2.Where(t2 => t1.Id == t2.value1 || t1.Id == t2.value2)
       .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new 
    { 
        t1.Id,
        t2.value3
    };
```